# Img center with a z-index

Tags: html, css, z-index, image

I'm trying to make an avatar creation site, but the images won't center. I tried everything in my book. Anyone have any ideas where I'm going wrong?

```
<img src="avatar/body_blue.png" class="body" id="body0"/>
<img src="avatar/body_green.png" class="body" id="body1"/>
<img src="avatar/body_grey.png" class="body" id="body2"/>
<img src="avatar/body_orange.png" class="body" id="body3"/>
<img src="avatar/body_purple.png" class="body" id="body4"/>
```

And here is this CSS:

```
.body {
    z-index:7;
    position:absolute;
    width:575px;
    height:750;
    margin:0px auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

[You can view it live here](http://www.xronn.co.uk/avatar).

Comment: you cannot use "margin: 0 auto;" with "position: absolute;" it wont work

Comment: how do you want CSS use marging: auto and absolute position at the same tim e?

Comment: Ahh, so the absolute voids the flow thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

```
 .body {
 margin:0 auto;
 display:table;
```

}

Comment: Display, table never heard of that one before going to do some reading. Why doesn't the margin auto trick work in this situation?

Comment: Display tables works well for centralizing a div . it doesn't need width atrribute.

Comment: @user1910046 margin:auto will not work in this because :
you are using position absolute here.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you read about CSS a little, here is a good example of centering anything.

http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Comment: thanks, in all the projects i've done margin auto fixed it thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this is to place your `<img>` tags inside a `<div>` that has already been centered. This way you can keep your `<img>` tags absolutely positioned so your images stay stacked on top of eachother.

"An absolute position element is positioned relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static." - [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp). Meaning your absolutely positioned `<img>` tags will be placed relative to your container `<div>`.

Updated HTML:

```
<div class = "container">    
    <img src="avatar/body_blue.png" class="body" id="body0"/>
    <img src="avatar/body_green.png" class="body" id="body1"/>
    <img src="avatar/body_grey.png" class="body" id="body2"/>
    <img src="avatar/body_orange.png" class="body" id="body3"/>
    <img src="avatar/body_purple.png" class="body" id="body4"/>
</div>
```

Add this CSS class:

```
.container{margin: 0px auto; width: 575px;}
```

Comment: I changed it to relative it unstacked all the images group onto of each other. I think for this to work I need this div to be nested and the outer div to be positioned aswell

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply I tried your method above and it unstacked 1 of the images, but not all of them its strange. I can upload the results if you wish

Comment: Yeh i think the solution for you is to place all of your <img> tags inside a <div> that has been centered using margin: 0px auto.

Comment: This way you can keep the absolute positioning on your <img> tag, so that the images stay stacked on top of eachother.

Comment: Ok, make sure that your <div> has a fixed width ie. width: 575px

Comment: got it working thanks so much man! I would vote this up if it let me thanks again!

Comment: Great, I have updated my original answer to show the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok i just checked your CSS and came up with the following changes :

1. Remove the width from `#avatar`
2. Remove `position:absolute;` from `.body`

This will center the big fluffy animal you have.

Answer (score 0):

You have styled the DIV #avatar with the following:

```
#avatar {
position: relative;
width: 300px;
height: 350px;
```

If this is the DIV you want centered on the page, then change the styling to:

```
#avatar {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 300px;
height: 350px;
```